# Twilio chat events memberUpdated, and userInfoUpdated never fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, twilio, twilio-api

i'm looking on what cases are these events is firing, i have implement it on these code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var chatChannel;
  var chatClient;
  var username;
  var $input = $('#chat-input');

  $.post("/tokens", function(data) {
    username = data.username;
    chatClient = new Twilio.Chat.Client(data.token);
    chatClient.getSubscribedChannels().then(createOrJoinGeneralChannel);
  });

  function createOrJoinGeneralChannel() {
    // Get the general chat channel, which is where all the messages are
    // sent in this simple application
    // print('Attempting to join "general" chat channel...');
    var promise = chatClient.getChannelByUniqueName("#{params[:chat_channel]}");
    promise.then(function(channel) {
        chatChannel = channel;
        console.log("#{params[:chat_channel]} is exist");
        console.log(chatChannel);
        setupChannel();
        return channel.getMembers();
        // $input.removeClass('.hidden')
    })
    .then(function(members){
      members.forEach(function(member){
        console.log('member', member);
        member.on('userInfoUpdated', function(){
          console.log('userInfoUpdated', member);
        })
      })
    })
    .catch(function() {
        // If it doesn't exist, let's create it
        console.log("creating #{params[:chat_channel]} channel");
        chatClient.createChannel({
            uniqueName: "#{params[:chat_channel]}",
            friendlyName: 'General Chat Channel'
        }).then(function(channel) {
            console.log("Created #{params[:chat_channel]} channel:");
            console.log(channel);
            chatChannel = channel;
            setupChannel();
        });
    });
  }

  function setupChannel() {
    chatChannel.join().then(function(channel) {
      printMessage(username + ' joined the chat.');
      chatChannel.on('typingStarted', showTypingStarted);
      chatChannel.on('typingEnded', hideTypingStarted);
      chatChannel.on('memberJoined', notifyMemberJoined);
      chatChannel.on('memberLeft', notifyMemberLeft);
      chatChannel.on('memberUpdated', updateMemberMessageReadStatus);
    });
    chatChannel.on('messageAdded', function(message) {
      printMessage(message.author + ": " + message.body);
    });
  }

  function updateMemberMessageReadStatus(member){
    console.log('memberUpdated');
    console.log('member.lastConsumedMessageIndex', member.lastConsumedMessageIndex);
    console.log('member.lastConsumptionTimestamp', member.lastConsumptionTimestamp);
  }

  function leaveCurrentChannel() {
    if (chatChannel) {
      chatChannel.leave().then(function (leftChannel) {
        console.log('left ' + leftChannel.friendlyName);
        leftChannel.removeListener('messageAdded', function(message) {
          printMessage(message.author + ": " + message.body);
        });
        leftChannel.removeListener('typingStarted', showTypingStarted);
        leftChannel.removeListener('typingEnded', hideTypingStarted);
        leftChannel.removeListener('memberJoined', notifyMemberJoined);
        leftChannel.removeListener('memberLeft', notifyMemberLeft);
        leftChannel.removeListener('memberUpdated', updateMemberMessageReadStatus);
      });
    }
  }

  function showTypingStarted(member) {
    console.log('somebody is typing');
    $('#is_typing').html(member.identity + ' is typing...');
  }

  function hideTypingStarted(member) {
    $('#is_typing').html('');
  }

  function notifyMemberJoined(member) {
    console.log('notifyMemberJoined');
    printMessage(member.identity + ' joined the channel');
  }

  function notifyMemberLeft(member) {
    console.log('notifyMemberLeft');
    printMessage(member.identity + ' left the channel');
  }

  $input.on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      chatChannel.sendMessage($input.val());
      $input.val('');
    } else {
      //console.log('typing');
      chatChannel.typing();
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    // var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

    (e || window.event).returnValue = leaveCurrentChannel(); //Gecko + IE
    return leaveCurrentChannel();                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
  });

});
```

and i've take alook to the console to see if my

```
console.log('userInfoUpdated', member);
```

or these guys

```
console.log('memberUpdated');
console.log('member.lastConsumedMessageIndex', member.lastConsumedMessageIndex);
console.log('member.lastConsumptionTimestamp', member.lastConsumptionTimestamp);
```

and they are never fired, during my test on the chat events, and i'm confused on how exactly i'm going to display how my users online or the status of a message is read or unread

so please enlighten me on the case, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

According to the JS docs for the latest version of Twilio Chat, the event you need to listen for on members is just called [`'updated'`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.1/docs/Member.html#event:updated). So, listening for `'userInfoUpdated'` won't work.

I would also recommend that within this code:

```
chatChannel.join().then(function(channel) {
  //...
  chatChannel.on('memberUpdated', updateMemberMessageReadStatus);
  //...
})
```

you use the `channel` passed to the callback, rather than the original `chatChannel` object. Like this:

```
chatChannel.join().then(function(channel) {
  //...
  channel.on('memberUpdated', updateMemberMessageReadStatus);
  //...
})
```

I don't know if this will fix the issue, but I can't think of anything else right now.